# How to upload binary data using AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2, zendesk

I was looking for a method to execute this

```
curl -u username:password -H "Content-Type: application/binary" \
   --data-binary @file.dat -X POST \
   "https://helpdesk.zendesk.com/api/v2/uploads.json?filename=myfile.dat&token={optional_token}"
```

I tried using this

```
[afnetworkmanager POST:url parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

        [formData appendPartWithFileData:attachment.attachmentData name:@"image" fileName:attachment.fileName mimeType:attachment.mimeType];

    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
       // TODO:

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
       // TODO:
    }];
```

But it did not help. Currently I am getting an error saying

> 

```
{
>     "Cache-Control" = "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate";
>     Connection = "keep-alive";
>     "Content-Length" = 345;
>     Server = "nginx/1.4.2";
>     Status = "201 Created";
>     "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
>     "X-Runtime" = "1.471856";
>     "X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
>     "X-Zendesk-API-Version" = v2;
>     "X-Zendesk-API-Warn" = "Removed restricted keys [\"image\"] from parameters according to whitelist"; } },

> NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type:
> text/plain}
```

I dont understand where I am wrong.

Comment: Nalin, how are you providing the zendesk authentication? I'm also trying to do this and so far have not had success. Can you post the correct answer that allowed this to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I eventually got this to work by using the AFURLSessionManager. Here is the complete code:

```
NSString *uploadAttachmentURL = @"https://mydomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/uploads.json?filename=screenshot.jpeg";

        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        _afHTTPSessionManager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

        // hack to allow 'text/plain' content-type to work
        NSMutableSet *contentTypes = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:_AFOpManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes];
        [contentTypes addObject:@"text/plain"];
        _afHTTPSessionManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = contentTypes;

        [_afHTTPSessionManager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"[USERNAME]" password:@"[PASSWORD]"];



        [_afHTTPSessionManager POST:uploadAttachmentURL parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"screenshot" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
        } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
            DDLogError(@"screenshot operation success!  %@", responseObject);
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
            DDLogError(@"Operation Error: %@", error);
        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

```
    configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{@"CS090-Version":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ios_%@",VERSION];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];


    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes  = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:apiURL parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:nil error:nil];

    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
    uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:imgData progress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
        }
    }];

    [uploadTask resume];
```